# Command line tool to copy files with verification

Tags: windows, file-management, command-line

Is there any Windows 7 x64 command-line software to copy files (similar to robocopy) which also **verifies** the copied files, e.g. does a --checksum or --ignore-times comparison after the copy. Preferable is the --ignore-times thou its slower than checksum.

It would be nice if it can also pause and resume the copy operation.

Comment: Pause and resume in the command prompt is going to be tricky

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by tricky?